# Margin off in Ipad on specific div

Tags: css, ipad, html, width

I have gotten everything centered and with a full width on the ipad EXCEPT for the main Nav bar and the rotating banner. Try as I might the coding works for everything except these.

Website is: [www.madcatz.com](http://www.madcatz.com)

```
#topNav {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* bottom: 1000px; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 9951;
  }
.bgstretcher ul li a span{
    background-image: url(images/bg-front-title.png);
    bottom: 100px;
    display: block;
    font-family: "UniversLTW01-85ExtraBkO"!important;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 15px 35px 15px 85px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 45%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Your website contains a lot of messy HTML and CSS. My suggestion is to first clean it up a little bit and try to strip down things that you don't need. It is very difficult to fiddle with a huge page like this using JSFiddle on the iPad. Second suggestion is to create a trimmed down version that has the same problem, but then a lot smaller.